# Restore a SQL Server 2008 database to SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup, restore, sql-server-2012-express

When I try to restore my `.bak` file, a SQL Server 2008 database file from my production server, to my local SQL Server 2012 Express server, I get the following screenshot:

[image]

Where I see `No backupset selected to be restored` and an empty dropdown under `Database`, see the areas marked in red.
As you can see, the OK button is greyed out and I can't select a database. So I'm not even getting errors, I can't start the restore entirely.

What can I do?

Comment: How **big** (in GB) is your database? The Express editions are limited in database size - the 2012 version supports a max size of 10 GB.

Comment: It's about 1GB. ps I see someone voted to close this question...can I see somewhere what the reason for that would be?